# Missing features for nodes in a Graph Neural Network (GNN)

Tags: neural-networks, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

I have built an undirected graph that I want to use to train a binary classifier.

The graph represents a network of clients connected through the addresses they used to register. For example, if my partner and I live in the same house, we would show up as `C1 -> A1 <- C2`, where `Ci` represents the `i`-th customer and `Ai` is the `i`-th address.

In other words, my edges table looks as follows:

| src | dst |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | A1 |
| C2 | A1 |
| … | … |

As you can see, I have two types of nodes: customers and addresses (this is NOT the label I want to predict, though!).

I'm using this graph to predict a binary outcome that only customers can have (for example, if they've committed credit card fraud). Likewise, I only have observable features for customers. I have neither a flag nor features for addresses.

For example, my attributes table looks as follows (completely excludes nodes that represent addresses):

| customer_id | X1 | … | Xp | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 42 | … | 784.53 | 1 |
| … | … | … | … | … |
| Cn | 39 | … | 1042.22 | 0 |

How should I train a GNN to predict a `target` considering that all the nodes that represent addresses lack both a target and features?

Some options I have considered:

- Fill missing values with zero and interpret the features/target as the product of $\text{is_customer}_i \times X_{i,p}$ (where $\text{is_customer}_i$ is 1 for customers and 0 for addresses).
- Treat the graph as a [heterogeneous graph](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/heterogeneous.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can train GNN. However, I would introduce one more feature that differentiates Customers from addresses. So, for example, `1` is assigned to all customers and `0` gets assigned to addresses. Then you can set the Xp variables to 0 or -1 for the addresses.

For the loss-calculation, you can exclude the addresses from the loss-function.